# Formulário, PHP e MYSQL - mysqli_num_rows sempre igual a zero

Tags: php, mysql

Amigos, estou fazendo um trabalho pro bono para um serviço público, e estou há dias tentando descobrir qual o problema do meu código. Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço demais.

```
O formulário é esse:

<html>

<style>

::-webkit-input-placeholder  { color:#CDCDCD; }
input:-moz-placeholder { color:#CDCDCD; }
textarea:-moz-placeholder { color:#CDCDCD; }

</style>


<form name="saque" action="https://equadsaude.000webhostapp.com/bancodados_atualizar.php" method="POST">

<table>

<tr>
<td>Processo</td>         </tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="n1" placeholder="somente algarismos"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Valor total sacado</td>   </tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="n4" placeholder="00000.00"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Observações e Data </td> </tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="n3" ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td col span="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Atualizar"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

E o arquivo .php (que está no servidor local) que ele deveria chamar é esse:

```
     <?php

$conectar = new mysqli("localhost","id1019345_dados_zzzz","xxxx", "id1019345_sobras") or die(mysqli_error());

    $processo = $_POST[ 'n1' ] ;
    $valor_sacado = $_POST[ 'n4' ] ;
    $observacoes = $_POST[ 'n3' ] ;

    //variavel de teste do POST no banco de dados
    $teste = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT 'id' FROM 'Tab_Index' WHERE 'Processo' = '$processo' ");
    while (mysqli_num_rows($conectar, $teste) == 0)
    {
    echo "<p>Não existe o registro informado. Verifique novamente no Banco de Dados.</p>";  exit(mysqli_error());
    }


    //variavel para cálculo do Valor da Sobra no banco de dados
    $sql_seleciona = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT 'Valor_sobra' FROM 'Tab_Index' WHERE 'Processo' = '$processo' ");
    while ($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conectar, $sql_seleciona))
        {
        foreach($query_row as $key => $value)
                           {
                           $resultado = $value-$valor_sacado;
                           }
        }

    //variavel para selecao das Observacoes no banco de dados
    $sql_seleciona2 = mysqli_query ($conectar, "SELECT 'Observacoes' FROM 'Tab_Index' WHERE 'Processo' = '$processo' ");
    while ($query_row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conectar, $sql_seleciona2))
        {
        foreach($query_row2 as $key => $value)
                           {
                           $resultado2 = $query2."/". $observacoes;
                           }

         }

    //Update do banco de dados
    $sql_alterar = mysqli_query($conectar, "UPDATE 'Tab_Index' SET 'Valor_sobra' =  '$resultado1', 'Observacoes' =  '$resultado2' WHERE 'Processo' = '$processo' ");

    if  ( isset ($sql_alterar) )
    {
    print "<h3> Valor da sobra atualizado com sucesso </h4>\n" ;
    }
    else 
    { 
    print "<h3> Erro ao atualizar </h4>\n" ;
    }


      ?>
```

O problema é que sempre aparece a mensagem " Não existe o registro informado. Verifique novamente no Banco de Dados.", que eu coloquei como aviso caso não encontrasse nada no Banco de Dados.
Só que mesmo quando eu coloca um número de Processo que existe no banco de dados, ele segue dando essa informação. E se eu retiro do script essa conferência, aparece a mensagem final "Valor de sobra atualizado com sucesso", como se houvesse ocorrido o Update do banco de dados, mas quando vou conferir no Banco de dados, nada foi alterado.

Impressão que eu tenho é que a interação com o banco de dados não está ocorrendo, por algum motivo que não sei qual é.

A tabela na DB tem 4 colunas: id, Processo (BIGINT), Valor_sobra (DECIMAL 7,2), Observacoes (VARCHAR). 
HOST: localhost USERNAME: id1019345_dados_zzzz SENHA: xxxx DB: id1019345_sobras

Answer (score 1):

Cara, em primeiro lugar, jamais jamais jamais JAMAIS passe uma string de formulário direto na query desse jeito. O jeito correto, usando o mysqli é o seguinte:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Agora vamos ao problema:

Na hora de pegar a quantidade de linhas que voltou, você só precisa passar o resultado da query, não precisa da conexão. Ou seja:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM teste");
$linhas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
echo $linhas; // 256
```

referência: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Isso por que o objeto retornado para a variável resultado será usado na contagem, a conexão com o banco de dados nem é mais necessária, só se você for fazer outra query.

**O outro problema**

Só que mesmo a verificação está errada depois do seu `UPDATE`, por que você está verificando se a variável foi definida em algum momento (`isset()`). Mesmo que ele não consiga realizar a operação, a variável foi definida sim, só que para um valor bastante eficaz: `FALSE`! Só que, como sua pergunta foi "Essa variável está definida?", ele sempre vai retornar `TRUE` e seguir pro bloco dentro da condição.

Então a forma correta pode ser duas:

```
if ($sql_alterar) {
  (...)
}
```

Que eu não gosto, pessoalmente, pois não fica muito claro o que você está verificando, mas certamente ele vai seguir pro `else` se não conseguir fazer o `UPDATE`. Prefiro assim:

```
if ($sql_alterar !== false) {
   (...)
}
```

Por que aí tenho certeza, na hora que bati o olho, que estou preocupado se essa variável é falsa.